# Using QGraphicsView.fitInView( ... ), how can I predict whether scrollbars will be needed?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I have a PyQt5 project where I create complex geometrical objects in a QGraphicsScene, and them show them in a QGraphicsView - standard stuff.

When I run my code on a large (1920x1080) monitor, the scene is displayed nicely with no scrollbars. However when I run it on a 1366x768 device, the viewport is too small, and I only see a part of the object, with scrollbars.

(In both cases, the window starts maximised.)

To fix this, I added the following code when the window is initialised:

```
my_view.fitInView(my_scene.sceneRect(), Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
```

and this works perfectly on the small monitor. However, on the large monitor, the viewport is now made smaller, and the scene is smaller than before.

So I try to predict in advance whether the scene is going to fit in the view or not, and print out some sizes to try to work out how:

```
print("A", my_scene.sceneRect().size())
print("B", my_view.size())
print("C", my_view.viewport().size())
```

And I get this:

```
A PyQt5.QtCore.QSizeF(227.0, 702.0)
B PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(640, 480)
C PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(621, 478)
```

I get the same set of numbers before and after fitInView(), on both displays.

How can I predict whether or not the scene will fit in the view without scrollbars, so that I don't make the graphic smaller when it doesn't need to be, but still is rescaled when it is not going to fit?

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: "I get the same set of numbers before and after". Did you expect those values to change? `fitInView` doesn't change the viewport size, and the scene rect is certainly not modified (nor it should!). What you need to check is how the scene rect *can* fit the viewport size, and that's simple math: can a 227x702 rectangle fit in a 640x480 *without* the scroll bars?

Comment: @musicamante ok, but then why does it display in entirety on one monitor size, not the other? presumably Qt has been able to resize (enlarge) the view to fit, but how can I detect this?

Comment: @eyllanesc - I would like to but at the moment pressures of getting the job done don't allow that. I have a decent workaround (detecting the monitor size) which is OK for now. If I have time later will surely do that.

Comment: @danmcb if it shows scroll bars in one screen and not on another, then there's probably something else you didn't show us (that's why a MRE is important); is it possible that those screens have different DPI values? Also consider that using `fitInView` in a resizeEvent might trigger some level of recursion (as explained in the docs).

Comment: all possible. Will try a mre later when I can. Thank you.